# How do you figure out the signs in factorization of this high-degree polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Rather than carrying out the whole factorization, in this case you only need to be able to identify patterns (this question is from a study guide, not an actual test or problem set).

You are given this polynomial:
$$x^2-4x+4-4y^6$$

And you have to choose the correct factorization from a few options, all variants of $(x+2+2y^3) (x+2+2y^3)$ but with different +/- signs on each term. The correct solution is: $$(x-2-2y^3) (x-2+2y^3)$$

But my question is, how do you know what the signs should look like?
I would appreciate either a specific or generalized answer, whatever seems more appropriate.

Many thanks!

Comment: Joke answer: given it's multiple choice, I would just plug in specific values of $x$ and $y$ (such at $x=y=1$) into the original expression and into the given options and ascertain which one outputs the correct value.

Comment: @ZainPatel Doesn't seem like a joke to me. Teachers who write exams which can be hacked by clever students deserve to have their exams hacked by clever students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : The third binomial formula is $$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$$

Here, you have $(x-2)^2-(2y^3)^2$. Take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

you will have $$x^2-4x+4-4y^6=(x-2)^2-(2y^3)^2=(x-2-2y^3)(x-2+2y^3)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ By Vieta the given roots $\,r,r' = \pm2\pm2y^3$ have sum $= 4$ so $\,r,r' = 2\pm 2y^3,\,$ which, indeed, have product $\,= 4-4y^6.$

**Alternatively**,  $ $ notice that the root product is a *difference of squares*

$$ 4-4y^6 = 2^2-(2y^3)^2 = (2-2y^3)(2+2y^3)$$

**Remark** $\ $ Thus you don't need to know/discover the general factorization formula in the other answers - which arises because *completing* the square leads to a *difference* of squares, e.g.

$$\begin{eqnarray}x^2-4x+4-4y^6 &\,=\,&\!\!\!\! \overbrace{(x-2)^2}^{\rm\!\!\! complete\ the\ square\!\!\!}\!\!\!\!\!\!-\!(\color{#c00}{2y^3})^2\ \ \text{so, factoring this} \it\text{ difference of squares}\\
 &\,=\,& (x-2\,\ -\,\ \color{#c00}{2y^3})\,(x-2+\,\color{#c00}{2y^3})\\
\end{eqnarray}$$ Here is a less trivial example

$$\begin{eqnarray} n^4+4k^4 &\,=\,& \overbrace{(n^2\!+2k^2)^2}^{\rm\!\!\! complete\ the\ square\!\!\!}\!\!\!-\!(\color{#c00}{2nk})^2\ \ \text{so, factoring this} \it\text{ difference of squares}\\
 &\,=\,& (n^2\!+2k^2\ -\,\ \color{#c00}{2nk})\,(n^2\!+2k^2+\,\color{#c00}{2nk})\\
&\,=\,&(\underbrace{(n-k)^2}_{\rm\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! complete\ the\ square\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}\ +\ \,k^2)\ \ \underbrace{((n+k)^2}_{\rm\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! complete\ the\ square\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!} +\,k^2)\\ \end{eqnarray}$$